# Leightweight Free PHP Filemanager

Tags: php, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have integrated TinyMCE as WYSIWYG in my cms admin section. i don't have file manager for it. I am searching for filemanager for it.

Want suggestions which one is good and free for it?

Comment: leightweight and simple to integrate with tinymce. Easy to upload, download and delete files

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this url:

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/filemanager/upload_files.php

It's totally integrated with TinyMCE.

Answer (score 1):

Ther are the following

**1. MCFilemanger for Tinymce** (that is the moxiecode product AurelioDeRosa mentioned):
http://www.tinymce.com/enterprise/mcfilemanager.php

**2. Another Ajax file/Image manager**
http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Tinymce-Ajax-File-Manager/

**3. Here is a blog entry listing a lot of possible filemanagers you may use with tinymce**:
http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/cms/file-and-image-management-plugins-for-tinymce/

Answer (score 0):

http://rosefinch.sourceforge.net/ will help

Answer (score 0):

This is one I've made for TinyMCE 3.x with step by step instructions on how to set up (TinyMCE v4.x has been released and the plugin needs rewriting to be compatible with this version): http://www.designsandcode.com/261/open-manager-tinymce-file-manager/

*Note: my previous post was deleted, I have no idea why, I am answering the question with a free solution which I have spent many hours developing, I'm hoping it would be of use to the asker or someone else searching this topic.*

Comment: The reason your post is deleted is likely because it contains only a link to some external blog post. It is subject to link rot in case your website becomes unavailable.

Comment: Ahh I see thanks, however most of the other links on the page before me are of the same nature :/

Comment: There was a change in stance about allowing link only answers. So please bear with it and write a bit more about it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will think of some extra info I can add

Answer (score 0):

This is a really nice project. Easy integration to other project, plugins for TinyMCE, CKEditor and CLEditor. It's free for personal or non-profit website and with donation, you get commercial permission. Files are on Github.

https://www.responsivefilemanager.com/